CHSH optimal winning strategy by matrix derivation for observables
For CHSH games if the players share EPR state then the maximal Bell violation is $2\sqrt{2}$ which can be proved by Tsireson's bound(here we consider the case where the shared state is fixed to be EPR). I am thinking if this optimization problem can also be proved by matrix derivation on its Lagrangian. That is
\begin{align}
\max_{P_0,P_1,Q_0,Q_1} Tr[(P_0\otimes Q_0+P_0\otimes Q_1+P_1\otimes Q_0-P_1\otimes Q_1)EPR]
\end{align}
where $P_0,P_1,Q_0,Q_1$ are observables so the constraints are $P_0^2-I=P_1^2-I=Q_0^2-I=Q_1^2-I=0$.
$Tr(P_0\otimes Q_0)EPR=\langle vec(P_0),vec(Q_0)\rangle$, thus $\frac{\partial{Tr(P_0\otimes Q_0)EPR}}{\partial P_0}= Q_0$. When the constraints are derived, we have $\frac{\partial{(P_0^2-I)}}{\partial P_0}=(\frac{\partial{vec(P_0^2-I)}_{ij}}{\partial vec(P_0)_{kl}})_{ijkl}=P_0\otimes I+I\otimes P_0$.
The Lagrangian $L(x,\lambda)=f(x)+\sum_i\lambda_i h_i(x)$, where $f$ is the objective function and $h$ are constraints. Here the constraints are matrix functions while the objective is a scalar. If we derive on the norm of constraints then I am afraid it can't be expressed by $P_0$ easily. Is there any better way be to convert the constraints and do the matrix derivation?
